# Viel und wenig plus Adjektiv

Tags: standard-german, declension, adjective-ending

*Viel* und *wenig* können vor unzählbaren Nomen stehen. Sie haben dann keine Endung. Wenn ein Adjektiv hinzugefügt wird, wie wird das Adjektiv dekliniert? So wie *viel sauberes Wasser* und *viel leckere Butter*?

Comment: Die Frage ist nicht klar. Wollen Sie wirklich wissen, wie das hinzugefügte Adjektiv dekliniert wird, oder eher, ob _viel_ und _wenig_ nach Hinzufügen eines Adjektivs dekliniert werden müssen?

Comment: Nicht ganz.Ich will wissen,nach wenig und viel , wie wird die Endung des Adjektivs geändert,wenn wenig und viel vor unzählbaren Nomen stehen.

Answer (score 7):

Simple Antwort:
Genau wie ohne die Wörter „viel“ oder „wenig“.

> - „grüne Pflanzen“ – „viele grüne Pflanzen“
> - „sauberes Wasser“ – „viel sauberes Wasser“
> - „leckere Butter“ – „wenig leckere Butter“
> - „gemahlenes Mehl“ – „wenig gemahlenes Mehl“

Comment: Dank schön.Sie sind so nett